# Why does the symbol style preview in the layers panel change to black fill？

Tags: qgis

When I change the spacing property of the line pattern fill in the layer style to meter at scale, the symbol style preview in the layers panel becomes a black fill. But the display in the map view is normal.Is there a kind man who can tell me the specific reason and how to solve this problem?
[image]

[image]

[image]